# Should I split my data between testing and training if I only care about feature importance?

Tags: data-science, data-analysis

Basic question, but I have some data and am trying to see which features are the most important in predicting the outcome of the target variable. I have no plan to make predictions with the data. Given this, should I still be splitting the data into training and testing, and if so, why?
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the purpose of crossvalidation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301462/what-is-the-purpose-of-crossvalidation).

Comment: You should read about cross validation to understand why you need it when training a model.

Answer (score -1):

IMO if you're just trying to see which features most accurately define your data, via ANY method - like clustering or chi-square, etc. Then no, you don't need to split your data-set. However, if you don't trust some of the feature-selection methods, and are trying to find the best one - you should split your data, and test the accuracy of these Feature Selection Models based off your train data, inside your test data.

Good luck!